# Why doesn't this regex match my newline separated key=value pairs?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex to validate an input that should follow these rules:

- 0 or more lines (separated by `\n`, `\r`, or `\r\n`)
- Each line is made by: from 1 to 100 `a-zA-Z` characters, then 1 equal sign, then from 1 to 100 alphanumerical character, then an optional newline

**Examples that match:**

```
a=1
foo=bar
```

```
a=1
b=2
```

(extra empty line is ok)

**Examples that don't match:**

```
a
```

(missing the equal sign and the value)

```
1=1
```

(key has a number)

```
a=1
b=
```

(second line missing value)

**What I tried:**

`(?<key>[a-zA-Z]{1,100})[=](?<value>[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,100}[^\r\n|\r|\n]{1})`

But this is not matching, while I expect it to:

```
a=one
b=two
c=3
d=33
eee=eee
```

The `c=3` line is not matching.

See https://regex101.com/r/C039en/2/

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to validate such strings, you probably need something like `^[a-zA-Z]{1,100}=[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,100}(?:(?:\r\n?|\n)[a-zA-Z]{1,100}=[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,100})*$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vg2vPO/1))

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew why not use backreference inside the non-capturing group.

Comment: @VishalSingh Do you mean a PCRE pattern like `^([a-zA-Z]{1,100}=[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,100})(?:\R(?1))*$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vg2vPO/2))?

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! Please post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a PCRE regex engine, you can use

```php
^([a-zA-Z]{1,100}=[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,100})(?:\R(?1))*$
```

Or, if it is not PCRE compliant:

```js
^[a-zA-Z]{1,100}=[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,100}(?:(?:\r\n?|\n)[a-zA-Z]{1,100}=[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,100})*$
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/Vg2vPO/2)  and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/Vg2vPO/1).

**Details #1**

- `^` - start of string
- `([a-zA-Z]{1,100}=[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,100})` - Group 1: one to a hundred ASCII letters, `=`, one to a hundred ASCII alphanumeric chars
- `(?:\R(?1))*` - zero or more repetitions of any line break sequence followed with Group 1 pattern
- `$` - end of string.

**Details #2**

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z]{1,100}=[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,100}` - one to a hundred ASCII letters, `=`, one to a hundred ASCII alphanumeric chars
- `(?:(?:\r\n?|\n)[a-zA-Z]{1,100}=[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,100})*` - zero or more repetitions of CRLF, CR or LF line ending, and then one to a hundred ASCII letters, `=`, one to a hundred ASCII alphanumeric chars
- `$` - end of string.